# Printing a messagebox in quo

Tags: python, printing, command-line-interface, pypi

I just installed quo **2022.1.6** from PypI [quo](https://pypi.org/project/quo)
, I'm trying to print a messagebox but I keep encountering an error

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
   import quo

   def main():
       quo.MessageBox(
           title="Message pop up window",
           text="Do you want to continue?\nPress ENTER to quit.",) .run()                                       

   if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

Check the documentation for more mitigation steps https://quo.rtfd.io